# CSS3 Card Flip force entire animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I am adding a class to my card on the jQuery event Mouseover, and removing the Class on Mouseout. Now I want that the card flip animation will execute fully, even If I leave the Div with the mouse.

This is my code:

```js
jQuery('.card').each(function(){
   jQuery(this).mouseover(function() {
       jQuery(this).addClass("flipped");
   });

   jQuery(this).mouseout(function() {
       jQuery(this).removeClass("flipped");
   });
});
```

```css
.flipContainer { 
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  perspective: 800px;
  border:1px solid black;
}

.card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.card figure {
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.card img{
    width: 90%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-top: 5%;
}

.card p{
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.card .front {
}
.card .back {
  transform: rotateY( 180deg );
}

.card.flipped {
  transform: rotateY( 180deg );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="flipContainer">
  <div class="card">
    <figure class="front"><p>1</p></figure>
    <figure class="back"><p>2</p></figure>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="flipContainer">
  <div class="card">
    <figure class="front"><p>3</p></figure>
    <figure class="back"><p>4</p></figure>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/* From Modernizr */
function whichTransitionEvent(){
var t;
var el = document.createElement('fakeelement');
var transitions = {
  'transition':'transitionend',
  'OTransition':'oTransitionEnd',
  'MozTransition':'transitionend',
  'WebkitTransition':'webkitTransitionEnd'
}

for(t in transitions){
    if( el.style[t] !== undefined ){
        return transitions[t];
    }
}
}

/* Listen for a transition! */
var transitionEvent = whichTransitionEvent();
transitionEvent && e.addEventListener(transitionEvent, function() {
console.log('Transition complete!  This is the callback, no library needed!');
});

/*
The "whichTransitionEvent" can be swapped for "animation" instead of "transition" texts, as can the usage :)
*/
```

The code is not from me, but this allows you to have an event on the end of the transition. This way you can just have a variable which is the state of your animation on the client.

You are now free to see when you want to remove a class or not.

A way to do it would be having a variable representing if the transition has been finished or not, and a variable representing the state.

Then when mouseover, mouseout or transitionEvent is called, just remove/add the class depending on those two variables.

Comment: Because I got multiple Cards on the page, I stored the State of the Transition in the Elementdata `jQuery(this).data("state", true);`. Works perfectly thanks a lot.